# What does this Omega theme warning / notice mean?

Tags: theming

I’m getting this Notice repeatedly on my [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) site, in various places. Not sure though exactly what is triggering the notice. This Notice is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$dir in omega_css_alter() (line 276 of /home/lovetrib/public_html/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/template.php).
```

And the line #276 in the Omega template file is

```
$pattern = $GLOBALS['language']->dir == 'rtl' ? '/\.no-query(-rtl)?\.css$/' : '/\.no-query\.css$/';
```

I believe it’s looking for a no-query.css file….?

To remedy I put a file named `omega.no-query.css` in the css folder. Since Omega is a base theme there is also a `mytheme.no-query.css` file in my theme’s css folder.

Can someone explain precisely what that line is doing and how to fix?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Explaining why `$GLOBALS['language']->dir` produces that warning is off-topic for us. That is plain PHP. Also, you cannot fix it; it must be the mantainer that fixes the module you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The $pattern needs to be filled with one of the values to the right of the question mark. To find which value to use, Drupal checks the global variable `$GLOBALS['language']->dir` if it contains the value 'rtl'. If this is true, the first value is assigned, otherwise the second. Basically this is a short notation of if-else.

The problem is, that `$GLOBALS['language']->dir` does not exist, so php throws an error.

The lines part should read `$GLOBALS['language']->directory`
There seems to be [a fix here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/omega/commit/?id=f190fb7), which is from 2014, so there is a good chance this fix was already integrated into production.

You might be able to fix this issue by upgrading the Omega-Template to the latest stable or maybe development version (after creating backups!)